# Connect for the first time

Tags: macos, svn

I'm using SVN for the first time for a project.
The admin created an account for me where the project is stored, and I have a username and a password.
However, I have no idea what I should do with it.

I can connect on the Redmine server using browser and see all the files stored, but I can't find anything similar to "adding my rsa pulic key" like with git.

When I'm doing "svn co https://myProject" in the terminal, it says :

> "svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL"

I'm sure the URL is the right though.
Is there something I'm missing ? How am I supposed to use that username/password thing ?

Thanks

Comment: You are sure your URL is `https://myProject` and not `https://www.example.org/myProject` or `https://www.example.org/svn/myProject`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it was my proxy that was blocking the access.. My bad ^^'